# C program gives unexpected output

Tags: c, floating-point, integer, printf, rounding

This is my C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
main(){ printf("%f", 5/3); }
```

I expect an output of `1.000000`, but what I get as an output is `0.000000`. Can someone explain why?

Comment: Do you see some warning on built?

Comment: @purplepsycho: Probably not.  The `main()` without a return type indicates that he's not using C99 or C11, though then the missing `return 0;` leads to an undefined value being returned to the environment as the exit status.  If the compiler isn't warning about such issues, it won't warn about format mismatches.  He needs to either turn on more warnings or get a better compiler — probably the latter.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I guess in C, the default return type for a function is `int`, and `return 0;` is implicit, so no need of that. Thanks by the way!

Comment: Only very old C (C89/C90) has default return type of `int`; both C99 and C11 require an explicit return type.  Therefore, if you omit the `int`, you must be using very old C.  However, very old C does not have the implicit `return 0;` from the end of `main()`; that was added by C99.  Therefore, your code is flawed in very old C because it should be explicitly returning a value from `main()`.  You can't have it both ways at once.  Now, whether the compiler you're using is going to notice and complain is a separate issue.  The chances are you're not using the warning options that trigger them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You use the wrong format specifier. The result of `5/3` is an `int` (integer), which is what you pass to `printf()`. In your format you use the `%f` modifier, which means `float`. Using the wrong `printf()` modifier is undefined behavior, meaning this could do anything, like in your case show 0.

To solve it, cast the result of the division to a `float`, like this:

```
printf("%f",(float)(5/3));
```

This will print 1.0, as expected.

Remember you can also type, for example:

```
printf("%lf", 5./3);
```

In order to transform the 5 into a floating-point value of type `double` containing 5. Note that you will then perform floating-point division, so the result would be 1.3333 then.